# Creating a First Person camera in Open GL 2.0 and glm

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I am farly new to Open GL, and c++ and have come across the issue of creating a first person camera. I don't understand matrix math so that makes it all the more harder for me. So far, for calculating the rotation of the camera I have gone for this:

```
void CameraFP::calculate_view()  {
    m_view = glm::rotate(m_view, this->get_rotation_x(), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
    m_view = glm::rotate(m_view, this->get_rotation_y(), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
}
```

That function is called every update call.

For handling the rotation of the camera via the mous, I've done the following:

```
void CameraFP::process_mouse(sf::Window *app)  {
    GLfloat mouse_x = app->GetInput().GetMouseX();
    GLfloat mouse_y = app->GetInput().GetMouseY();

    GLfloat mouse_x_delta = std::max(mouse_x, old_mouse_x) - std::min(mouse_x, old_mouse_x);
    GLfloat mouse_y_delta = std::max(mouse_y, old_mouse_y) - std::min(mouse_y, old_mouse_y);

    y_rot += mouse_x_delta / (float)app->GetWidth();
    x_rot += mouse_y_delta / (float)app->GetHeight();

    this->old_mouse_x = mouse_x;
    this->old_mouse_y = mouse_y;

    app->SetCursorPosition(app->GetWidth() / 2, app->GetHeight() / 2);
}
```

and for handling the movement I've done the following:

```
void CameraFP::process_keyboard(sf::Window *app)  {
    const sf::Input *input = &app->GetInput();

    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::W))  {
        position.z += 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::S))  {
        position.z -= 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))  {
        position.x -= 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))  {
        position.x += 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
}
```

My issues lie in the fact that my camera does not move in the direction you face, and that it never stops rotating :/. Also, if you could point me to a guide or something on Matrix math that would be awesome :)

**Edit 2:**'

I just started a new process mouse function, and it a movement along the x axis of the screen as a y rotation for the camera correctly. However, it doesn't matter if I move the mouse left or right, both movements rotate me right. Same with the x axis in 3d space, but this happens downwards. Any ideas on what is causing this?

```
void CameraFP::process_mouse(sf::Window *app)  {
    GLfloat mouse_x = app->GetInput().GetMouseX();
    GLfloat mouse_y = app->GetInput().GetMouseY();

    GLfloat mouse_x_delta = old_mouse_x - mouse_x;
    GLfloat mouse_y_delta = old_mouse_y - mouse_y;

    if (mouse_x_delta > 0)  {
        y_rot += mouse_x_delta / (float)app->GetWidth() * 0.1f;
    } else if (mouse_x_delta < 0)  {
        y_rot -= mouse_x_delta / (float)app->GetWidth() * 0.1f;
    }
    if (mouse_y_delta > 0)  {
        x_rot += mouse_y_delta / (float)app->GetWidth() * 0.1f;
    } else if (mouse_y_delta < 0)  {
        x_rot -= mouse_y_delta / (float)app->GetWidth() * 0.1f;
    }


    if (mouse_x != old_mouse_x)  {
        m_view = glm::rotate(m_view, y_rot, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    }
    if (mouse_y != old_mouse_y)  {
        m_view = glm::rotate(m_view, x_rot, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
    }

    this->old_mouse_x = mouse_x;
    this->old_mouse_y = mouse_y;

    app->SetCursorPosition(app->GetWidth() / 2, app->GetHeight() / 2);
}
```

Comment: A couple of tips: reset your view matrix to identity before applying the absolute rotations; multiplications between matrices are not commutable so the order of parameters matter. [Here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) you can find more info.

Comment: @Gigi Great resource, Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to look for my camera code at the moment, but what I can tell you right now is, that your movement calculation is simply wrong.
 You aren't taking the camera rotation into account.
You have to do something like this:

```
if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::W))  {
    position.z += sin(camera_rot_y);
}
else if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::S))  {
    position.z -=  sin(camera_rot_y);
}

if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))  {
    position.x -=  cos(camera_rot_y);
}
else if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))  {
    position.x +=  cos(camera_rot_y);
}
```

Also you can use "else if"s, because you cannot move forward and backward at the same time.^^

Also, why are you using std::min() and max() in the following code?:

```
GLfloat mouse_x_delta = std::max(mouse_x, old_mouse_x) - std::min(mouse_x, old_mouse_x);
GLfloat mouse_y_delta = std::max(mouse_y, old_mouse_y) - std::min(mouse_y, old_mouse_y);
```

If you want to rotate in the opposite direction you need to get a negative delta, which is impossible with your code. Get rid of the min() and max() functions.

BTW: My camera code is not the most efficient (uses rotate instead of direct calculations), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show usage of `position` in `CameraFP` and `m_view` but I think problem si here:

```
void CameraFP::process_keyboard(sf::Window *app)  {
    const sf::Input *input = &app->GetInput();

    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::W))  {
        position.z += 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::S))  {
        position.z -= 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))  {
        position.x -= 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))  {
        position.x += 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
}
```

You must multiply matrix, with this translation, and `m_view`. In matrix multiplication is important order of matrices. First must be `m_view` because it is main matrix, and you want move forward from `m_view` rotation. But there is `glm` namespace and there is method `glm::translate` which them multiply in right order and you just create `glm::vec3` as parameter of that method (translation with x, y, z).

(If you use **relative position** ... only difference between frames)

So you must change it like this:

```
void CameraFP::process_keyboard(sf::Window *app)  {
    const sf::Input *input = &app->GetInput();

    glm::vec3 pos;
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::W))  {
        pos.z += 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::S))  {
        pos.z -= 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::A))  {
        pos.x -= 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }
    if (input->IsKeyDown(sf::Key::D))  {
        pos.x += 1.0f / 100.0f;
    }

    //Make translation
    m_view = glm::translate(m_view, pos);

    //Values at position 12, 13, 14 are translation x, y, z
    //Save absolute position of camera
    position = glm::vec3(m_view[12], m_view[13], m_view[14]);

}
```

PS: Sorry for my poor english.